# Custom Estimator Head for scoring vector of probability distributions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using TensorFlow 1.4 and the Estimator framework.

I'd like to use `tf.contrib.estimator.multi_head` to create one head (in a model that has one other head) that summarizes the result of N `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. The N probability distributions are each defined over the same set of classes, but are independent distributions. The summary loss score I'd like to compute is simply the sum of squares of the softmax cross entropy losses.

I can almost use a `tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head` to compute the summary if I fake a `labels` vector of N zeros, as mean squared error with a zero vector is equivalent to summing the squares of the softmax losses. But this seems kludgy and I'd like a more direct approach.

It seems that I will need to create my own subclass of `_Head` implemented in `tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.head`, and will have to implement the method `create_loss` which is documented as to be used by framework developers.

Before I start down this path, I'd like to hear if there are alternate approaches I should consider.

I originally started development with Keras and at one time had a multihead model using the functional API. I wonder if perhaps I should return to using Keras, and then create my `model_fn` using the `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`. All things being equal I would prefer to code in pure Tensorflow idioms, but perhaps Keras is the easiest path forward.

Comment: do you mean ensemble multiple estimators ?  do you need to train them all together or can they be trained separately and then just reduce their respective model results into single answer?

Comment: I want to use the Estimator framework to train one model with more than one "head" -- more than one output, each trained against different labels. I'm working on a game playing algorithm using techniques inspired by Alpha Go, and as the Alpha Go team learned, I believe one model trained to do two different but related regressions will work better than training two separate models.

Comment: Another way to look at the model I want to create is that it will have N+1 heads, but I want just two loss functions, not N+1 loss functions.